# How do I summarize the actual values of a data column insteadt of just the number of rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summarize

I have a conflict record where each entry/row shows a conflict event. Each event also shows the number of deaths. The dataset covers the years 2017-2022 and 10 different regions. Thus, there are different numbers of entries shown for each year and region. I now want to generate a new data frame that shows me one entry per year for each region, in which all deaths of that year in that precise region are added & shown (one row per year per region). Basically, as a result, each region has 6 entries (one for each year).

I know this command combination to get the sum of the entries displayed:

```
data_mali%>%
  dplyr::group_by(admin1, year)%>%
  dplyr::summarise(dplyr::n())
```

"

However, I now need the actual values of the entries summed. How do I do that?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: For the actual values summed have you tryed?:   summarize( SUM = sum() )

Answer (score 0):

`summarise()` is a similar verb to `mutate()`. You can replace a variable or create a new variable using functions like `sum()`, `mean()`, and `first()`.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```r
data(mtcars) # example dataset
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
   group_by(cyl, wt) %>% 
   summarise(mpg = mean(mpg),  
             gear = first(gear), 
             total_hp = sum(hp))
```